# Symfony 2 AJAX session expire

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, session

I have an AJAX worker they is called a API url every second. After 250-300 seconds, I don't get a valid response or a profile-token in case of the user was logged out. I have already configured the `cookie_lifetime` to **0** but it made no difference. Here's also my security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            login_path: /home
        logout:
            path: logout
            handler: app.custom_logout
            target: /home
```

The weird thing is, it seems completely random when a session expires. I have also reached over 1000 AJAX calls and on the other side only 300 calls.

I hope any one of you can help me.

PS: The AJAX calls are not only a JSON response, there are full generated twig templates (including a profiler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer for my question by myself.

You need to configure the `gc_divisor`, `gc_probability` and `gc_maxlifetime`. For example:

```
session:
    cookie_lifetime: 0
    gc_divisor: 10000
    gc_probability: 1
    gc_maxlifetime: 604800
```

After this configuration in your `config.yml` the chance that your session expire (because you have set `cookie_lifetime` to a specific time) is equal to zero.

Also have a look to the Symfony documentation of sessions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session